# VSCode "please clean your repository working tree before checkout"

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code I made some changes which I do not want to commit en sync yet. However, after my holiday, I want to sync the files from the server (changes from my colleagues). So In Visual Studio Code I want to do a sync.

I get a message "Please clean your repository working tree before checkout"

What do I need to do to get the files of my colleagues without losing my own uncommitted changes?

Answer (score 86):

In my experience the best way to **stash the changes** is like so:

[image: stash]

**sync the changes** from your co-workers and afterward do stash-pop like so:

[image: stash pop]

You may also perform these actions in the terminal:

- [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)
- [`git stash pop`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#git-stash-pop--index-q--quietltstashgt)

Comment: very well explained, thanks!

Answer (score 29):

Create a temporary branch and commit the changes. Or if you don't want to create a temporary branch - stash the changes.

Comment: I will do that, thanks. Additional question. What command do I need to use to clean the repository working tree?

Comment: Committing to temporary branch or stashing the changes will clean the working tree

Answer (score 3):

for my case i simply had unstaged a file i went back and selected the file on my terminal and staged the file and i was free and ready to merge and commit

Answer (score 2):

Not only should you stash, but VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020) will be even safer with:

> ### [Git: Prompt to save files before stashing](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/d9a6977d8a5d2c0f9f0fb28227ac4a022d558c3b/release-notes/v1_52.md#git-prompt-to-save-files-before-stashing)
>
> VS Code will now prompt you to save unsaved files whenever you attempt to stash changes.

Answer (score 2):

in my case I had free working tree but VC code still say 'Please clean your repository working tree before checkout.'. I used `git push -f origin` to force push to origin. Maybe it will helps for someone!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you activated rebasing.

Another way to fix this without having to stash is

```
git config pull.rebase false
```

Answer (score 0):

what worked for was to just remove the unstaged changes from source control list that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i used

> git push -f origin

and it worked fine

Comment: It may have worked for you but while answering questions you should try to explain why it worked and what it does.

Answer (score -2):

What worked for me was to clean working tree to default state using the command below:

```
$ git clean -xfd
```

or

```
$ git clean -x -f -d
```

Before stashing

```
$ git stash
```

Answer (score -12):

1、Discard changes;
2、Synchronize Changes